# Its possible to convert 2.1834e+14 to the real extensive number

Tags: c++, linux, numbers

i made this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long double ln=0, nc=0;
    char choice;

    cout<<"Number1: "; cin>>ln;
    cout<<"Number2: "; cin>>nc;
    cout<<"Result: "<<pow(ln,nc);
    cout<<"Continue?(y/n): ";
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice=='y') {
        main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The numbers, if are to long come up ,for example, like this "2.1834e+14". There is a way to convert it to the real extensive number?

Comment: What is "the real extensive number"?

Comment: If you want more digits you could use `setpercision`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably looking for [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) stream manipulation if you dont want the cout to display scientific notation.

You can also look for `setprecision(n)` in which you have to include this library

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Also there are some libarary like **[GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/)** which are used to store very large numbers. For example:- 2^1000 needs a 1001 bit integer to be represented without losing precision. So the GNU MP library may help.